# Regex parsing text and get relevant words / characters

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to parse a file, that contains some programming language. I want to get a list of all symbols etc.

I tried a few patterns and decided that this is the most successful yet:

```
pattern = "\b(\w+|\W+)\b"
```

Using this on my text, that is something like:

```
string = "the quick brown(fox).jumps(over + the) = lazy[dog];"
re.findall(pattern, string)
```

will result in my required output, but I have some chars that I don't want and some unwanted formatting:

```
['the', ' ', 'quick', ' ', 'brown', '(', 'fox', ').', 'jumps', 'over', 
' + ', 'the', ') = ',  'lazy', '[', 'dog']
```

My list contains some whitespace that I would like to get rid of and some double symbols, like `(.`, that I would like to have as single chars. Of course I have to modify the `\W+` to get this done, but I need a little help.

The other is that my regex doesn't match the ending `];`, which I also need.

Comment: You know that `(\w+|\W+)` is just *everything*, right? I'd recommend using something like https://regex101.com/#python for explanation and testing.

Comment: `\b([a-zA-Z]+)|([^a-zA-Z ])` should work

Comment: No, it´s not just everything. The first takes every word or number, the second takes any Symbols. The first `\w+` is lowercase, the second uppercase.

Comment: @Scareactor that doesn't mean "symbols", it's every word character (`\w`) and every character that's not a word character (`\W`). It's *every character*, including whitespace etc. Please learn a little about regex before proceeding.

Comment: yep, and surrounding are some borders.

Comment: works, thank you. Is there a way to get just the value part of the tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `\W+` for one or more, if you want single non-word characters in output? Additionally exclude whitespace by use of a [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Also it seems like you could drop the word boundaries.

```
re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w\s]", str)
```

This matches

- `\w+` one or more word characters
- `|[^\w\s]` or one character, that is neither a word character nor a whitespace

[See Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/fwsJXG)